# is there a way to get the executed mysql out of the cursor?

Tags: python, mysql

To prevent attacks I use the python mysql connector with the sql and data seperation.

I prepare a sql statement like sql="select * from x where x.id = %s"
and a data array with data=['21']

cursor.execute(sql,data)
will do the rest.

But for debugging it would be helpful to get the stmt which is created inside execute, from sql and data, out of the cursor.
Maybe someone can point me to that.

Comment: I'm not sure that's how prepared statements work

Comment: Maybe [General Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) may help?

Comment: `cursor.statement` will give you this